# Electron - File path issue in distribution build

Tags: windows, reactjs, electron, fs, electron-builder

Developing an app in electron and react, everything is working fine in development mode but in production mode, I'm getting path issue.

Windows - v 10
Electron - v1.8.9
React - v16.3

When the app opens, raising an event for downloading data from server to local system for displaying in offline mode.

In development mode with internet the file paths as below

```
"D:\Workspace\Electron App\images\image01.jpg"
"D:\Workspace\Electron App\images\image02.jpg"
"D:\Workspace\Electron App\images\image03.jpg"
```

In distribution mode without internet the file paths are like this

```
"C:\Program Files\Electron App\resources\app.asar\images\.eslintignore"
"C:\Program Files\Electron App\resources\app.asar\images\app"
"C:\Program Files\Electron App\resources\app.asar\images\app.js"
"C:\Program Files\Electron App\resources\app.asar\images\node_modules"
```

From above URL `app.asar` is a file not a folder, and i'm not able to find the downloaded files, and i'm not sure why the URL has `.eslintignore - app - app.js`

Here is my code to download files

```
const downloadFile = (configuration) => {
    const { remoteFile, localFile } = configuration;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = request({
            method: 'GET',
            uri: remoteFile,
        });

        const out = fs.createWriteStream(localFile);
        req.pipe(out);

        req.on('end', () => resolve());

        req.on('error', () => reject());
    });
};

ipcMain.on(STORE_DATA, (event, data) => {
    const storedPaths = [];
    const dataLength = data.length;
    const storingPath = path.join(__dirname, '/images/');

    data.map((remoteFileSource) => {
        const filename = remoteFileSource.url.split('/').pop().split('#')[0].split('?')[0];

        downloadFile({
            remoteFile: remoteFileSource.url,
            localFile: storingPath + filename,
        }).then(() => {
            const storedData = {
                url: storingPath + filename,
            };
            storedPaths.push(storedData);

            // Send paths to local files
            if (dataLength === storedPaths.length) {
                mainWindow.send(STORED_DATA, storedPaths);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Looking forward for much needed help

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using [.getPath](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetpathname)

This API lets you find explicitly a given path name

Comment: thank you so much for your response, I have not tried. but I'm getting the files location in the callback from path. `"C:\Program Files\Electron App\resources\app.asar\images\Image01.png"
`

Comment: but when i explicitly tried to get files from the above path, there is no such file.

Comment: Can you please tell me where would be the ideal place to store the file in the local system. because I tried to create a folder, windows is throwing error `ERROR: EPERM, operation not permitted, mkdir`

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer I figured it out, actually, i was storing the files in the wrong directory.

Comment: Happy that i could assist, take care!